# Adding custom logic to declarativeNetRequest

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have logic that used webRequestBlocking, where I'd redirect the request, if the request param matched some dynamically changeable values stored in background script, i.e. if user is placing orders for items 1,2,3 and my background script says, dont allow messages to item 1, then I'd in that case redirect the webrequest, do a check that the requestBody doesnt have item 1 set.

I am trying to do the same in V3, but I can't find a way, given there isnt a way for me to call any of my own custom methods from background script, I thought I can maybe just update rules to match for the requestBody params, but I can't seem to find a way to do that even?

Is there anything that can be done here? Not sure why would they remove support for something so important?

Comment: There's no way. If you're lucky you can precompute the values using regexFilter+regexSubstitution. As for ManifestV3, it's designed by impractical idealists who genuinely consider this lack of flexibility a negligible price to pay for the benefits that their tunnel vision paints them as significant.

Comment: @wOxxOm - haha, nicely said!